# Using Super to break class into separate classes (and separate files)

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to break a large class into separate subclasses, which I then intend to break into separate files by function.  I thought the code below would work, but it seems I have the class/subclass logic incorrect.  My example code is:

```
class MyParentClass():
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

class SubClass(MyParentClass):
    def __init__(self, x):
        super().__init__(x)

    def test(self):
        print("Test inside of SubClass")

    def test2(self):
        print(self.x)

z = MyParentClass("hello")
z.test()
z.test2()
```

The end-goal is to have:

1) MyParentClass the main class that is called.

2) Have multiple SubClasses that exist in separate files (e.g. ACL, Policy, Routes in acl.py, policy.py, and routes.py)

I don't know if this is possible, but what I envision is:

```
z = MyParentClass("172.16.16.1")

# would exist in acl.py
z.acl("permit any any") 

# would exist in policy.py
z.policy("permit any any") 

# would exist in route.py
z.route("route 0/0 next-hop 172.16.16.2") 

# would exist in MyParentClass
z.save()
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`MyParentClass` shouldn't be a parent class, but a [Registry](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/registry.html), and have a [`__call__`()](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__) method that is a [Factory Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).